# TableView Showing Map Annotation Titles and Subtitles

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am trying to create a table view that shows a list of my map annotations.  Each cell would contain the name(title) and address(subtitle).  I'm then going to add a search bar to the table view.  When I try to add the annotation titles and subtitles to an array for my table view, the array never gets any objects added to it.  It's count is still 0. Any help?

Here is how I'm adding the annotations to my map view:

```
for (int x = 0; x < [lat count]; x++)
    {
        marketAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        location.latitude = [[lat objectAtIndex:x]floatValue];
        location.longitude = [[lon objectAtIndex:x]floatValue];
        marketAnnotation.coordinate = location;
        marketAnnotation.title = [title1 objectAtIndex:x];
        marketAnnotation.subtitle = [subtitle1 objectAtIndex:x];
        [marketLocations addObject:marketAnnotation];
    }

    [worldView addAnnotations:marketLocations];
```

I have tried adding this to the loop to add the title to my table view array but the array stays empty.

```
[list.marketList addObject:marketAnnotation.title];
```

EDIT: More code.

RSFM is my map view. List is my table view.

In RSFM, here is where I add the annotations to my map and add the annotation titles to the marketList array in List.

```
List *list = [[List alloc]init];
    list.marketList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int x = 0; x < [lat count]; x++)
    {
        marketAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        location.latitude = [[lat objectAtIndex:x]floatValue];
        location.longitude = [[lon objectAtIndex:x]floatValue];
        marketAnnotation.coordinate = location;
        marketAnnotation.title = [title1 objectAtIndex:x];
        marketAnnotation.subtitle = [subtitle1 objectAtIndex:x];
        [marketLocations addObject:marketAnnotation];

        [list.marketList addObject:marketAnnotation.title];
    }

    [worldView addAnnotations:marketLocations];

    NSLog(@"List Count: %d", [list.marketList count]);
```

List.h

```
@interface List : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *marketList;

@end
```

List.m

```
#import "List.h"
#import "RSFM.h"
#import "DTCustomColoredAccessory.h"

@interface List ()

@end

@implementation List
{

}

@synthesize marketList;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSLog(@"List Count: %d", [marketList count]);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [marketList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *marketListIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellImage.png"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:marketListIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:marketListIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:20.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundView = image;

    NSLog(@"cell separator style: %d separator color: %@", tableView.separatorStyle, tableView.separatorColor);

    cell.textLabel.text = [marketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DTCustomColoredAccessory *accessory = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:cell.textLabel.textColor];
    accessory.highlightedColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.accessoryView =accessory;

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably your array is not initialized.
Initialize it above for loop :

```
marketLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int x = 0; x < [lat count]; x++)
{
    marketAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    location.latitude = [[lat objectAtIndex:x]floatValue];
    location.longitude = [[lon objectAtIndex:x]floatValue];
    marketAnnotation.coordinate = location;
    marketAnnotation.title = [title1 objectAtIndex:x];
    marketAnnotation.subtitle = [subtitle1 objectAtIndex:x];
    [marketLocations addObject:marketAnnotation];
}

[worldView addAnnotations:marketLocations];
```

Comment: I initialized list.marketList and the count is what it should be but now when I click my bar button to show the table view, it's empty.  The count of that array goes back to 0.

Comment: @user2029585 That is probably because array is local to that method and you try to use it outside of method. If still problem persists then need to look at more of your code.

Comment: @user2029585 this is symptomatic of neglecting to set your table view'a delegate (either in IB or in code). Or failing to call `reloadData` after adding the data to the array (if you're loading the array asynchronously).

Comment: @user2029585 Is datasource set?

Comment: Do you use table in `List.m`? You initialize array in `RSFM`, whereas you use that array to load table in `List.m`. If you are using table in `RSFM` then shift table delegate and datasource methods to `RSFM` and implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableDataSource` in `RSFM`.

Comment: datasource is set.  The table view is in List.m. RSFM is the map view. The marketList array is created as a property in List.h.  It's contents are set in RSFM.m since that's where all of the map annotation info is.

Comment: Let me understand what you are trying to do. You create `List` object and populate an array. Then you want to display `List` view controller and titles in table at that time. Am I correct?

Comment: RSFM has a map view. In RSFM I create and add annotations to the map. There is a nav bar button that opens List.m to show a list in a table view of the titles and subtitles of the annotations. There is an array that is a property in List.h called marketList. That array should contain the annotation titles from RSFM.

Comment: You can see in the code I posted where I add the titles to the array. The problem is that the data in the array is not being retained in List.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31961/discussion-between-akash-and-user2029585)